# How to delete text from file using preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, regex

i want to delete text from `public function CreateUser` up to `//pfCreateUser`. so basically i want to delete function `CreateUser`.

for example i have file named `test.php` and in that file i have a text like this.

```
public function CreateUser(Request $request)
    {
        another code here, include a-zA-Z0-9 and special character...
    } //pfCreateUser
public function CreateCompany(Request $request)
    {
        another code here, include a-zA-Z0-9 and special character...
    } //pfCreateCompany
```

here what i try

```
$a = "test.php";
$b = file_get_contents("test.php");
file_put_contents($a, preg_replace("#public function CreateUser.*//pfCreateUser#m", "", $b));
```

but it not working.

i want the file will be like this after delete the text

```
public function CreateCompany(Request $request)
    {
        another code here, include a-zA-Z0-9 and special character...
    } //pfCreateCompany
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace` is working fine for me, provided that I use it in dot all mode, with the `/s` modifier.  I used the following pattern:

```
public function CreateUser\(.*\/\/pfCreateUser\s*
```

Sample script:

```
$output = preg_replace("/public function CreateUser\(.*\/\/pfCreateUser\s*/s", "", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
public function CreateCompany(Request $request)
    {
        another code here, include a-zA-Z0-9 and special character...
    } //pfCreateCompany
```

Note that the `.*` will match across newlines, because of the dot all mode `/s`.

Comment: thaks its working, but is that posible to delete the "enter" space?
my code now like this after delete `\n\n\n code here`.

Comment: Yes, add a `\s*` to the end of the pattern, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. is that case sensitive? and the last, can u please explains the code that u create? so i can learn from it.

Comment: It is case sensitive, use `/i` for case insensitive.

Comment: hi, can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408844/how-to-delete-string-with-regex-preg-replace-php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line with a little Regex and just putting the frist and last word you want to cut out:

`preg_replace('/public[\s\S]+?pfCreateUser/', '', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents($a, preg_replace("/^public function CreateUser[\s\S]*?pfCreateUser/", "", $b));
```