# How to delete string with regex preg_replace php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have full string like this:

`Route::post('asdasdasdad/{param1}/{param2}', 'Admin\RouteController@a212e12e');`.

and want to delete that route so in `preg_replace` i focus on

`Route::post('asdasdasdad` as start text and

`Admin\RouteController@a212e12e');` as last text.

here what i try

```
preg_replace("/Route::post('asdasdasdad\(.*Admin\RouteController@a212e12e');\s*/s", "", $string);
```

but its not working.

Comment: For starters, you seem to be escaping stuff in the wrong places. `post(` - the brace at the end here is supposed to be a literal one, so that one would have to be escaped. `asdasdasdad\(` - and here you are escaping it, meaning this demands a literal `(` in that place, which isn’t present in your data.

Comment: _“and want to delete that route”_ - meaning what, exactly? What is the exact desired result for the given input?

Comment: i want to delete all of this `Route::post('asdasdasdad/{param1}/{param2}', 'Admin\RouteController@a212e12e');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some errors in your regex, some un-escaped regex characters. try this

```
preg_replace("/Route::post\('asdasdasdad.*Admin\\\\RouteController@a212e12e'\);\s*/s", "", $string);
```

if you want to replace multiple lines in one go

```
preg_replace_all("/Route::post\('asdasdasdad.*Admin\\\\RouteController@a212e12e'\);\s*/s", "", $string);
```

witch works as if you add the `multi line` modifier to your regex

```
$string = file_get_contents('route.php');
$string = preg_replace("/Route::post\('asdasdasdad.*Admin\\\\RouteController@a212e12e'\);\s*/s", "", $string);
echo $string;
```

you get the line with `EOL` removed

Comment: @Jazuly can you provide the full route file and mark the routes you're trying to remove ?

Comment: @Jazuly wich lines re supposed to be removed? i dont see any significative markings. can you provide line numbes ?

Comment: line 24, you can search it :D

Comment: @Jazuly yeah, you need a double escape for the \ since it's a php string. edited my answer